# Where can I find all the files to run the code related to openpose repo

Tags: object, 3d, 2d, augmented-reality, detection

Does anyone have tried to run the repo [OnePose](https://github.com/zju3dv/OnePose.git)?
here I am trying to get output on pretrained model ${REPO_ROOT}/data/model/checkpoints/onepose/GATsSPG.ckpt but I don't have some dependencies to run it like  output_superpoint_superglue\sfm_ws\model can some one tell me where can I find these files?

I have tried to pass a dummy file but I dont know the exact format of these files that's why it fetching error ?